# Using selectors to make partial lines full on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-selector

I've got a requirement have a row of buttons which, when unpressed, have a series of indented lines separating them like so.[image]

When any of the buttons is clicked, I want the lines surrounding the clicked  button to extend to be full length like so:[image]

I've tried implementing this as a selector, but the problem I keep running into is that I can't have each button "own" both of its border lines.  For example, I can set up selectors such that each button has `android:right="1px"`, and alters its length via a new selector with `android:state_pressed="true"` but that means that the other buttons would not be able to alter their left border when they're clicked.

I know I could handle this pattern in code, but I feel like it would be ugly and hacky.  Is there any way to implement this in pure XML using a selector?  Also, note that I am using custom components which know whether they are on the left, right, or middle of a list.

Comment: Try set button selector background with two image one with half/partial line and another with full line .

Comment: I've tried that.  The problem is I can the first button's right border fully extend when I click it, but I'm unable to also make the same line extend when I click the center button since that line is drawn by the first button.